# Calling a javascript function with parameters in a for loop: is there a way to pause the loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters, delay

I have an array of data values and need to repeatedly call a javascript function with one after the other of those values as parameters. So I am doing a pretty straigthforward for-loop. My problem: I need to pause the execution of each step of the loop for a second, and I can't figure out how to do this.
I already fiddled around with setTimeout(), but that only works for the whole function, not for one iteration of the for-loop. Is there a way to pause the execution of the for-loop before the next iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to pause the execution of the for-loop before the next iteration?

Not in a normal function, no. Instead of a `for` loop, you handle the code for the first iteration, then schedule the next iteraton using `setTimeout`, repeatedly until you're done. A search for "`setTimeout` loop" will net you dozens of examples.

In an `async` function, you can use `for` if you give yourself a promise-enabled version of `setTimeout`:

```
const delay = (ms, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);

// ...
for (let i = whatever; i < whateverElse; i += something) {
    // Do the thing, then
    await delay(1000);
}
```

More about `async` functions [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 0):

edit: did you edit question or something, I read it as iterating and then random pause in middle of it, not every iteration 1second

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function* iterateArr () {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   console.log(`Number ${i}`)
    yield arr[i];
  }
}

let iterate = iterateArr();

let c = 0;
while (c < 4) {
 console.log(iterate.next());
  c++;
}
console.log("OTHER CODE");
console.log(iterate.next());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll dig into this and come back later.